# TypeORM + nextjs import entities with glob pattern

Tags: typescript, next.js, typeorm

How can I import entities with glob pattern as showed below, when I try to do so I get the following error:`SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

I tried the followed approaches:
`path.join(proccess.cwd(), '**/*Entity.ts')`,
`path.join(proccess.cwd(), '**/*Entity.js')` but none of them seems to work.

`"typeorm": "^0.3.10"`
`"next": "13.0.0"`

```
const dataSource = new DataSource({
    url: env.DB_DSN,
    type: 'postgres',
    synchronize: false,
    logging: IS_PRODUCTION ? undefined : ['query'],
    entities: [path.join(proccess.cwd(), '**/*Entity.ts')],
    logNotifications: true,
  });
```

Comment: try similar to: "entities": ["dist/src/db/entities/*.entity.{ts,js}"],

Comment: nextjs doesn't build to dist